# Modifying a custom element's light DOM using Stenicl.js is not working in Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, web-component, shadow-dom, stenciljs

I'm using Stencil.js library to build web components. The library loads a polyfill in Edge and IE11 in order to provide browser support for them since they lack native support for web components spec.

In Chrome, if I modify a [custom element's light DOM](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#composition_slot) using the native DOM API (appendChild, removeChild, etc.), and the shadow DOM contains a  element, Chrome re-parses the flattened Dom tree and the updates to the light DOM are reflected in the slot.

**This seems like it's maybe a bug or a limitation in the polyfill. Does anyone know if that's true and if there are any workarounds?**

Sample Code:

```js
    // web component
@Component({
  tag: "foo-component",
  shadow: true
})
export class Foo {
  return (
    <Host>
      <div class="stylin"><slot /></div>
    </Host>
  );
}
```

```html
<body>
  <foo-component><p>bar</p></foo-component>
</body>
```

```js
var newPar = document.createElement("p");
newPar.innerHTML = "bar2";
document.querySelector("foo-component").appendChild( newPar );
```

Expected flatten tree:

```html
<foo-component>
  #shadowRoot <!-- shadowRoot is simulated in Edge -->
    <div class="stylin><p>bar</p><p>bar2</p></div>
</foo-component>
```

Actual flattened dom tree:

```html
<foo-component>
  #shadowRoot <!-- shadowRoot is simulated in Edge -->
    <div class="stylin><p>bar</p></div>
    <p>bar2</p>
</foo-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither your "expected" nor "actual" are entirely correct. Both `<p>bar</p>` and `<p>bar2</p>` are in light DOM and should be *outside* the shadow root for browsers with shadow DOM:

```
<foo-component>
  #shadowRoot
    <div class="stylin"><slot>...</slot></div>
  <p>bar</p>
  <p>bar2</p>
</foo-component>
```

Only `<div class="stylin">` containing the slot is *inside* shadow DOM.

Only the most recent update to Edge (v76) supports shadow DOM - if you don't have that, you should see a different structure entirely. The polyfill for Edge does not add shadow DOM - it provides scoped styling - so unless you have v76 you should see everything in light DOM:

```
<foo-component>
  <div class="stylin"><p>bar</p></div>
  <p>bar2</p>
</foo-component>
```

Other than the "simulated" shadowRoot, this is the same as your "actual" and is what you should expect because you have appended the bar2 child to `foo-component` not `div.stylin`. Without actual shadow DOM support, there is no distinction between light and shadow DOM and therefore no slot.

Please inspect your DOM again to be sure - you shouldn't be seeing any shadowRoot in Edge < v76.

A workaround is to try to access the "slot" using a light DOM selector. If it's accessible, it indicates that there is no shadow DOM, so append the child to the "slot" element directly. Otherwise use the host element and let shadow DOM handle the slot access:

```
var newPar = document.createElement("p");
newPar.innerHTML = "bar2";
(document.querySelector("foo-component > div.stylin")
    || document.querySelector("foo-component)
).appendChild( newPar );
```

Comment: I think you're mistaking the 'flattened dom tree' with the 'shadow dom' or perhaps I used language which conflated the two. What I'm concerned about is the resulting `flattened dom tree`, which should be a merger between the `light dom` and the `shadow dom`. The flattened dom tree should contain the shadow dom that's defined inside the web component, as well as any distributed nodes that were placed from the light dom into the appropriate slots.

When light dom is modified, the browser should update the appropriate slots in the flattened tree by re-distributing the updated light-dom.

Comment: AFAIK, the polyfill doesn't provide a simulated shadow root, it just scopes the styles. So there is no shadow root or slots in Edge, simulated or otherwise. If you therefore use dom manipulation to add an element to a component, it becomes a direct child not a child of a "slot". The workaround is to check whether or not the "slot" is accessible in light dom, and if so use that because it indicates no shadow. I'll update my answer with sample code for the workaround.

Comment: You're right that the Stencil.js polyfill doesn't work this way. But the polyfill from webcomponents.org does simulate the light+shadow dom, probably using mutation observers.
https://www.webcomponents.org/polyfills